# Can't login with CakePHP's Auth login

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I know it's an overbeaten question, but I couldn't find the solution in all the answers. Perhaps you can help me. I'm trying to log a user in and I'm getting the "Username/password invalid" error with correct data. It' my first experience with cakePHP.

To the code.

Model:

```
App::uses('AppModel','Model');

Class User extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'Users';

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Costumer' => array(
            'className' => 'Costumer',
            'foreignKey' => 'users_id',
            'order' => 'Costumer.name ASC'
        )
    );

    //Suppressed the validation code, don't think it's important here

    public function beforeSave($options = array()){
        if (!empty($this->data['User']['pwd'])) {
            $this->data['User']['passwd'] = Security::hash($this->data['User']['pwd']);
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class UsersController extends AppController{

public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
public $name = 'Users';
public $components = array('Auth','Session');

public function beforeFilter(){
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('add');
}

public function login(){
    //Tests
    $userEmail = $this->User->findByEmail($this->request->data['User']['email']);
    $userPass = $this->User->findByPasswd(Security::hash($this->request->data['User']['passwd']));
    die(var_dump($userEmail, $userPass));

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->request->data['User']['passwd'] = Security::hash($this->request->data['User']['passwd']);
        if ($this->Auth->login()){
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('E-mail e/ou usuário incorretos, tente novamente.'));
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 40px;">
<div class="col-lg-8">

</div>
<div id="login" class="col-lg-2" style="background-color: #eee">
    <h3>Conecte-se.</h3>
    <?php 
        echo $this->Form->create('User', array(
            'label' => 'login', 
            'class' => 'form-horizontal form-group'
            )
        );
        echo $this->Form->input('email', array(
            'label' => 'E-mail',
            'class' => 'form-control',              
            )
        );
        echo $this->Form->input('passwd', array(
            'label' => 'Senha',
            'class' => 'form-control', 
            )
        );
        echo '<br />';
        echo $this->Form->end(array(
            'label' => 'Entrar', 
            'class' => 'btn btn-success'
            )
        );
     ?>
</div>
```

And my AppController.php has:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
//public $components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar');

public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'homemk'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'homemk'),
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'passwd'),
                'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
            )
        ),
        'authError' => 'Para visualizar esta página, você precisa estar logado.'
    )
);

public function beforeFilter(){
    $this->Auth->allow('display');      
    $this->set('authUser', $this->Auth->user());

}
```

}

The crazy thing is, both UsersController's lines

```
$userEmail = $this->User->findByEmail($this->request->data['User']['email']);
```

and

```
$userPass = $this->User->findByPasswd(Security::hash($this->request->data['User']['passwd']));
```

return the user I'm trying to login, so it doesn't seem to be data error.

Guys! What am I missing here?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Since I haven't found any way for doing this in an "elegant" way, I wrote a dummy workaround. It manually checks request->data values against database and manually logs the user in. That's a temporary solution, I'll be back to it later.

```
public function login(){
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->User->findByEmail($this->request->data['User']['email']);            
        if (!empty($user) && ($user['User']['passwd'] == Security::hash($this->request->data['User']['passwd']))){
            $this->Auth->login($this->request->data);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('E-mail e/ou usuário incorretos, tente novamente.'));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with the passwordHasher property of the Auth component and unfamiliar with Blowfish.

You should use Cake's built in password hasher

**User model**

```
public function beforeSave() {
    if (isset($this->data['User']['passwd'])) {
        $this->data['User']['passwd'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['passwd']);
    }
    return true;
}
```

**AppController**

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'homemk'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'homemk'),
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'passwd'),
            )
        ),
        'authError' => 'Para visualizar esta página, você precisa estar logado.'
    )
);
```

**UsersController**

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()){
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('E-mail e/ou usuário incorretos, tente novamente.'));
        } // end if cannot log in
    } // end if no form submitted
} // end login
```

Comment: It was a good hint, bowlerae, but still the same error is being shown. Bummer. It's odd, because I followed the 2.x cookbook and examples.

Comment: Go to your database quickly and change one of your user's passwd's to "23235bbc117a56627a5becf7a74cbfea0b49fa5a" this is the Cake password hash for the word "password". Then trying logging into that user using their email and typing in the word "password". It probably didn't work because the password was saved in your table using the old hash.

Comment: I don't think it was the problem, because I deleted all users from Users table and created a new one, using the AuthCompontent::password method. But I'll try that.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I tried changing the password directly in the database, as you suggested. It's the same crazy thing - it doesn't log the user in, but the test queries "findByEmail" and "findByPasswd" return correctely.

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with using email to log in a user. I have only ever used "username" but I've read the docs on using  "email" and it seems simple enough and your code looks correct.

Comment: I just wanted to add for anyone looking up this question, that each cake installation will hash password differntly I guess based on your Security.cipherSeed and Security.salt config settings. I just started working on a new cake application and users with the password "password" have a different hashed value than what I previously mentioned. AFNeirelles, this would explain why changing your passwords to that directly in the database did not work.